# Как записать условие в программе?

Tags: python, pascal, pascalabc.net

"Исходная строка содержит десять единиц и три двойки, других цифр нет, ТОЧНЫЙ ПОРЯДОК РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЯ ЕДИНИЦ И ДВОЕК НЕИЗВЕСТЕН."
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно записать условие, что точный порядок неизвестен?
т.е. сначала var s := 10*'1'+3*'2';
а как записать условие любого расположения этих цифр?
Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import random
s ='1'*10 + '2'*3
res = ''.join(random.sample(s, len(s)))
```

Ещё можно посмотреть на функцию `random.shuffle()`.

Answer (score 1):

Это же надо простейшее условие задачи изложить так сложно.
УСЛОВИЕ чего вы хотите ПРОВЕРИТЬ?

*Исходная строка содержит десять единиц и три двойки, других цифр нет,*  -- ок, если это условие,  и надо проверить, соответствует ли ИСХОДНАЯ строка этому условию, тогда зачем ваша проверка на количество вхождений?

А вот если это надо проверить, то:

```
st1='1112111211121'
if st1.count('1')==10 and st1.count('2')==3 :
    print ('Условию соответствует')
else:
    print ('Условию НЕ соответствует')
```

Если надо проверить, что других символов в строке нет, то:

```
if set(st1)=={'2','1'}:
    print ('Совпали по составу')
else:
    print ('Не совпали по составу')
```

Ну а дальше -  комбинируйте эти условия как вам надо.

Что вы хотели сказать этим оператором

```
var s := 10*'1'+3*'2'
```

и вообще, на каком языке он написан(на pascal что-ли?)  -  остается неразгаданной тайной.